# SVG hover effect doesn't work when added to a webpage as an image

Tags: image, dictionary, svg, hover, opacity

Still really new to this and needing a bit of help.

I made an svg image with hover effects using illustrator CC and Atom for some small edits along with some videos I watched online. It works perfectly when opened in a browser from desktop but when I try to add it to wordpress with an image tag or in a test website using plain html and an image tag the hover effect and area specific links to the anchors on my page stop working completely.

I don't fully understand all of the code generated by illustrator and the examples I saw online were much cleaner than what I have. But I don't know how to clean it up or of if all the data is necessary to keep? It's 1mb in size so too big for codepen.io sharing. You can view saved svg [here.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YBu_6tMa2sRTj-GC49PR48rfbJfMX0xE)

Your help is tremendously appreciated!

Comment: Don't use an image if you want hover effects, embed the SVG in some other way e.g. an object or iframe or inline.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for pushing me in the right direction! I was able to clean up the svg data a lot and put most of the styles inline except for the hover states which I don't think can be coded inline, right?

https://codepen.io/brittaniecampos/pen/BVPqrj

But when I add the code to my Wordpress site the link styles from the WordPress CSS are overriding my svg link styles and my svg doesn't appear correctly in the page at all.

http://i67.tinypic.com/m7vpu.png